# Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl'

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to generate an APK and this error is being installed me:

> Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl'

This logic after issu updated the Ionic from version 6.1.1 to 6.2.1. I have already tried to reverse a verdict but not a certainty.

Ionic Info:

```
√ Gathering environment info - done!

Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.2.1 (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 6.3.0, browser 5.0.4, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.1.4, (and 9 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Android\android-sdk)
   NodeJS            : v6.12.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 3.10.10
   OS                : Windows 10
```

I reinstalled the ionic and now it introduces me the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.0.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.0.1/builder-3.0.1.jar'.
         > Tag mismatch!
```

uninstalled and installed the Android platform. The following error is displayed:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl'.
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: aidl is missing from 'C:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\aidl.exe'
```

Comment: Hello, please post your "ionic info" in your question to give us more details. Also, have you tried removing the android plugin and adding it back?

Comment: thanks for answering. I added in the question my Ionic Info @StephenRomero

Comment: What command are you running in your console exactly? If you run "ionic cordova build android --prod --debug", you may get a little more info on why your build is breaking. Also, which plugin or package exactly are you referring to with the ionic versions you updated?

Comment: new error. I reinstalled the ionic and now it introduces me the following error.

Comment: Have you removed your android platform and re-added it?

Comment: Yes, I did now and I put the result in the question

Comment: Check this link, https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/build-fails-on-android-could-not-resolve-all-files-for-configuration/119024/6. It seems you may need to remove a specific directory related to your problem and re-build.